# How do i convert a Column to Int in Spark sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I would like to take the last 6 characters of string in a dataframe

```
 val loc ="/data/published/omega/omega_logs/20171205_4801"
 val df =sqlContext.read.avro(loc)
 val df1 = df.withColumn("sub_str", substring(df("broadcast_end_date_time"),9,14)).select("broadcast_end_date_time","sub_str")
```

The above code works . but I dont want to hardcode the 14 in my substring fuction . How do i find the length of a column and convert that as Int

```
 +-----------------------+-------+
 |broadcast_end_date_time|sub_str|
  +-----------------------+-------+
 |20171205124000         |124000 |
 |20171205254000         |254000 |
 |20171205143000         |143000 |
 |20171205111000         |111000 |
 |20171205124000         |124000 |
```

I am trying the below code  and I get below error

```
 val df1 = df.withColumn("sub_str", substring(df("broadcast_end_date_time"),9,length(df("broadcast_end_date_time")))).select("broadcast_end_date_time","sub_str")
```

It seems that length function returns a Column . How do i convert that to Int

```
 scala> val df1 = df.withColumn("sub_str", substring(df("broadcast_end_date_time"),9,length(df("broadcast_end_date_time")))).select("broadcast_end_date_time","sub_str")
 <console>:52: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: Int
   val df1 = df.withColumn("sub_str", substring(df("broadcast_end_date_time"),9,length(df("broadcast_end_date_time")))).select("broadcast_end_date_time","sub_str")
                                                                                      ^
```

Could someone help me to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are directly write the SQL query on your Dataset i am spark sql developer i done your requirement like this it may helpful for you.

```
actualDataset.createOrReplaceTempView("Test");
actualDataset.show();
 Dataset<Row> resultDataSet = spark.sql("SELECT value, substring(value, 9,length(value)) substr, length(value) length from Test");
resultDataSet.show();
```

output:

```
+--------------+
|         value|
+--------------+
|20171205124000|
|20171205254000|
|20171205143000|
+--------------+

+--------------+------+------+
|         value|substr|length|
+--------------+------+------+
|20171205124000|124000|    14|
|20171205254000|254000|    14|
|20171205143000|143000|    14|
+--------------+------+------+
```